# Select child in order even if it's inside another div

Tags: html, css

I want to know if there's a way to select elements like using nth-child but ignoring if it's inside another div, like:

```html
<div>
  <a class="first">1st</a>
  <a class="second">2nd</a>
  <a class="third">3rd</a>
  <div>
    <a class="fourth">4th</a>
    <div>
      <a class="fifth">5th</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="sixth">6th</a>
</div>
```

I will add, in according by its position, a color to each link and I want the colors to have a order. Of course I could just add a specific class to each one for this but will be a lot more complicated since some links may or not appear according the user/account type.
Now I'm using, for example:

```
a:nth-of-type(4n + 1) {
  color: pink;
}
```

But it's selecting all elements that are first child kkrying

Edit: What I want to achieve is to select each 1 out of 4 and so on, because I have four colors. Something like this:

```
<div>
  <a class="first">pink</a>
  <a class="second">blue</a>
  <a class="third">green</a>
  <a class="fourth">yellow</a>
  <a class="fifth">pink</a>
  <div>
    <a class="sixth">blue</a>
    <a class="seventh">green</a>
    <div>
      <a class="eighth">yellow</a>
      <a class="ninth">pink</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="tenth">blue</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is using js an option?

Comment: when you write `4n + 1` you mean to select all link (1, 5, 9, 13 ...) of the entire page/section?

Comment: @Gunther If there's no way in doing that by css then yeep

Comment: @tacoshy actually only all links inside a specific div, like it's the master parent lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think css can solve your problem, but a simple js can.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((el, index) => {
  if (index % 4 == 0)
     el.classList.add("pink");
  else if (index % 4 == 1)
    el.classList.add("blue");
  else if (index % 4 == 2)
    el.classList.add("green");
  else if (index % 4 == 3)
    el.classList.add("yellow");
});
```

```css
.pink {
  color: pink;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="first">pink</a>
  <a class="second">blue</a>
  <a class="third">green</a>
  <a class="fourth">yellow</a>
  <a class="fifth">pink</a>
  <div>
    <a class="sixth">blue</a>
    <a class="seventh">green</a>
    <div>
      <a class="eighth">yellow</a>
      <a class="ninth">pink</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="tenth">blue</a>
</div>
```

Edit: you've commented that it needs to be inside a master div, to do that just change the selector in the `querySelectorAll` function to something like `".container-div a"`

Comment: I guess it will have to be like this

Answer (score 2):

JS is useful here

```js
const cols = ["pink", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
[...document.querySelectorAll("#anchors a")].forEach((a, i) => {
  a.style.color = cols[i % 4];
});
```

```html
<div id="anchors">
  <a class="first">1st</a>
  <a class="second">2nd</a>
  <a class="third">3rd</a>
  <div>
    <a class="fourth">4th</a>
    <div>
      <a class="fifth">5th</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="sixth">6th</a>
</div>
```